# In remote sensing and image processing what does the term "spectral domain" mean?

Tags: remote-sensing, image-segmentation, mean-shift

In remote sensing and image processing what does the term "spectral domain" mean? How could this be understood in an image segmentation context?

In an article on segmentation of satellite images, the author informs that the spatial and spectral domain are the two most important parameters for a segmentation of the Mean-Shift type.

He writes like this:

> Spatial bandwidth hs is the spatial distance between classes in the
> spatial domain, and it indicates the spatial window size in the
> segmentation. Attribute bandwidth (or spectral bandwidth) hr
> represents the spectral difference between classes in the spectral
> domain. The mean-shift algorithm segments the image by grouping
> together all pixels that are closer than hs in the spatial domain and
> hr in the spectral domain and then connecting the corresponding
> convergence points.

https://doi.org/10.1016/j.isprsjprs.2015.04.010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider an image as a grid of pixels (ranging from [0-255] for a 8-bit pixel).

An RGB image is an image composed of a stack of 3 grayscale images, one for each of the 3 "color" channels.

The spatial domain refers to the spatial relationship between pixels of a grayscale image.

Whereas the frequency domain is basically its Fourier transform.

We are used to the 3 RGB channels with standard cameras and consumer electronics, but with, e.g. satellite sensors, images are said to be "multi spectral". Which means they are a stack of more than these 3 RGB channels. An image capture by a certain wavelength of such multi spectral sensor is called a band. E.g. [Landsat](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/what-are-band-designations-landsat-satellites) have up to 11 bands. [Sentinel-2](https://docs.sentinel-hub.com/api/latest/data/sentinel-2-l2a/) up to 13 bands.

Therefore, you can look at an image resulting from a multi spectral sensor as a "data cube".

Now take a pixel. What is behind that pixel, in the "depth" of the cube, is basically a spectrum because each channel captures a different wavelength.

Hence the term "spectral domain", it relates to the "depth" of that data cube, i.e. what happens and how the spectral information behaves and changes upon features in the image.

This article [[1](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/12/7/1097/htm#)] also makes use of these words.

This figure from [[2](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9133320)] may help visually understanding the concept:

[image]

You can also see this reference [[3](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Gerbil-A-Novel-Software-Framework-for-Visualization-Jordan-Angelopoulou/cceb34f8b2403ecd0605a73ef8d6e06b37aa4c86)].

Notice: it's a bit more complicated under the hood, because multispectral imagery is a "discrete" acquisition technique, whereas we speak about [hyperspectral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperspectral_imaging) imagery when we capture a continuous spectrum of part of the light.

- [1](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/what-are-band-designations-landsat-satellites): Lee, J.; Han, D.; Shin, M.; Im, J.; Lee, J.; Quackenbush, L.J. Different Spectral Domain Transformation for Land Cover Classification Using Convolutional Neural Networks with Multi-Temporal Satellite Imagery. Remote Sens. 2020, 12, 1097. https://doi.org/10.3390/rs12071097
- [2](https://docs.sentinel-hub.com/api/latest/data/sentinel-2-l2a/): Zhang, Wei & Du, Peijun & Lin, Cong & Fu, Pingjie & Wang, Xin & Bai, Xuyu & Zheng, Hongrui & Xia, Junshi & Samat, Alim. (2020). An Improved Feature Set for Hyperspectral Image Classification: Harmonic Analysis Optimized by Multi-scale Guided Filter (HGFM). IEEE Journal of Selected Topics in Applied Earth Observations and Remote Sensing. 3903 - 3916. 10.1109/JSTARS.2020.3006772.
- [3](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/12/7/1097/htm#): Jordan, Johannes and Elli Angelopoulou. “Gerbil - A Novel Software Framework for Visualization and Analysis in the Multispectral Domain.” International Symposium on Vision, Modeling, and Visualization (2010).

Comment: in this case how would it be possible to determine the value of the spectral domain of this cube? Would it be the sum of the wavelengths of the pixel stack in your example?